# i use angularjs controller to pass data array to laravel controller, but laravel received a string

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-4

Laravel controller:

```
function printBarcode($id=null)
{
    print_r($id);
}
```

AngularJS controller:

```
$scope.select = function(data) {
    console.log(Object.keys(data.items));
    var id=[];

    for(var i=0; i<Object.keys(data.items).length; i++)
    {
        Object.keys(data.items)[i];
        id.push(Object.keys(data.items)[i]);
    }
    $http.get('/printbarcode/'+id).success(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }).
    error(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}`
```

Blade template:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="barcodeData.items[<?php echo $items->item_code ;?>]"  value="{{$items->item_code}}" />
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/printbarcode/{id}',array('as'=>'printBarcodes','uses'=>'BarcodeController@printBarcode'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Whar do you wxpect with this: `print_r($id);`? It'a a string content in the response context. If you need a `json`  response then:

```
function printBarcode($id=null)
{
    return json_encode([$id], true);
}
```

Comment: its working.but i need to get that values on by one..now it came like this

 ` ["6211,6212"]
0
:
"6211,6212"
length
:
1 `

Comment: i need these ids to generate view

Comment: i need to access this id values